# How to create a summary statistics table by multiple categories (groups) using stargazer?

Tags: r, latex, summary, stargazer

I was wondering if there's a way to create a decent summary statistics table by multiple categories (groups) using `stargazer()`. I started with the following code but I am not sure how to advance from here.

```
library(mtcars)
mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, {
  vs <- factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  am <- factor(am, labels = c("automatic", "manual"))
  cyl  <- ordered(cyl)
  gear <- ordered(gear)
  carb <- ordered(carb)
})
summary1 = summary(mtcars2)
stargazer(summary1)
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [11] must be the same length as the vector [3]

Using `stargazer()` or other comparable packages, I want to make a summary statistics table categorized by transmission (`am`) and engine (`vs`) to be presented in the following way.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried using `stargazer()`? Could you include the code you have tried to highlight the stargazer coding problems you have?

Comment: @Peter I tried  `stargazer(summary)` and got 
`Error in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [11] must be the same length as the vector [3]` But even if I resolve this issue still my code does not realize the table above. I want to know how to code before I apply `stargazer()`.

Comment: Please include this code and error in the question as this is your coding problem. Where is `summary` defined, State how you resolved this issue and show what you get so it is easy to see what the problem(s) is(are).

Comment: @Peter, I just updated it.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve something like this with the `datasummary` function from the `modelsummary` package (disclaimer: I am the maintainer). You will find a detailed description and [many examples on the packages's website.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html)

Load the library and define a custom function to create a mean +/- sd. We use backticks because the name of our function includes spaces. Note that because of the unicode character, this may not work on Windows.

```
library(modelsummary)

`Mean ± SD` <- function(x) { 
    sprintf("%.0f ± %.0f", round(mean(x)), round(sd(x)))
}
```

Clean up variable labels:

```
dat <- mtcars
dat$am = ifelse(dat$am == 0, "automatic", "manual")
dat$vs = ifelse(dat$vs == 0, "v-shaped", "straight")
```

Finally, we use `datasummary` to create the table. A few things to note:

- Rows go on the left side of the formula
- Columns go on the right side of the formula
- Statistics and variables joined by a `+` will be displayed one after the other.
- Statistics and variables joined by a `*` will be "nested" inside one another.
- Parentheses can be used to nest several variables/statistics
- `1` is a shortcut for "all".

You will find detailed instructions and examples [on the package website.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html) This table can be exported to HTML, LaTeX, Word, and more using the `output` argument:

```
datasummary(
    mpg * (Min + Max + `Mean ± SD`) +
    hp * (Min + Max + `Mean ± SD`) +
    wt * (Min + Max + `Mean ± SD`) ~
    am * vs + 1,
    data = dat)
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to reshape the data beforehand. With this, you don't need to specify each variable individually in the formula:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, wt, hp, am, vs) |>
    mutate(am = ifelse(am == 0, "automatic", "manual"),
           vs = ifelse(vs == 0, "v-shaped", "straight")) |>
    pivot_longer(cols = c("mpg", "wt", "hp"),
                 names_to = "variables")

datasummary(
    variables * (Min + Max + `Mean ± SD`) ~ value * am * vs + Heading(`All`) * value,
    data = dat)
```